# Using a 2-d Array in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming problem and I need to take the user input in the form of a 2-d array and use the values from the 2-d array inside the function.
The values of the 2-d array will not be changed when used inside the function.

In the function int dp i am getting the 
       error:

declaration of 'a' as multidimensional array must have bounds for          all dimensions except the first

```
int max(int a,int b,int c)
{
if(a>=b && a>=c)return a;
if(b>=c && b>=a)return b;
else return c;
}
int max2(int a,int b)
{
if(a>b)return a;
else return b;

}


int dp(int i,int j,int a[][],int p,int q)
{
if((i-1)>=0 && (j-1)>=0 &&(i+1)<p &&(j+1)<q )
return  max(a[i][j]+dp(i-1,j+1,a,p,q),a[i][j]+dp(i+1,j+1,p,q),    
    a[i][j]+dp(i,j+1,p,q));
if(i==0 && j!=0 && (j+1)<q)
return max2(a[i][j]+dp(i+1,j+1,p,q),a[i][j]+dp(i,j+1,p,q));

}
int main()
{
int p,q,r,s,T,a,b,i,j,k;
scanf("%d",&T);
for(a=0;a<T;a++)
{
    scanf("%d %d",p,q);
    int z[p][q];
    int max=0;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<p-1;j++)
        scanf("%d ",&z[j][i]);
        scanf("%d",&z[j+1][i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
   {
    if(dp(i,0,z,p,q)>max)
    max=dp(i,0,z,p,q);
   }

  }

   }
```

Comment: 1) Use more than one letter for variable names. 2) If this is C++, then why not use a standard container, like `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the error message:

> declaration of 'a' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

Your function signature does not have bounds for `a`'s 2nd dimension:

```
int dp(int i,int j,int a[][],int p,int q)
//                     ^^^^^
```

You need to fill it in with `a[][N]` where `N` is whatever the correct bound is. The issue is that you are using VLAs here:

```
scanf("%d %d",p,q);
int z[p][q];
```

That is non-standard C++, and basically means you cannot write the signature of `dp`, since the second bound has to be known as a compile-time constant. You could either make it a single-dimensional array:

```
int* z = new int[p*q];

int dp(int i, int j, int* a, int p, int q)
//                   ^^^^^^
```

or dynamically allocate it in 2 dimensions and just pass it in that way:

```
int** z = new int*[p];
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    z[i] = new int[q];
}

int dp(int i, int j, int** a, int p, int q)
//                   ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you cannot leave both the index(row,column) empty in `int a[][]` in your function declaration. You must have both specified or atleast the value of column index.

Use dynamic declaration

```
int **z = new int*[p];
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
    z[i] = new int[q];
```

Change the parameter `int a[][]` to `int **a`

Comment: I cannot do that because the dimensions of array has to be taken from the user

Comment: If i do something like int a[][]  to int a[p][q] then it shows error That p and q are note declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

The function `dp` needs some information to perform meaningful index calculations, either done by the compiler or in the actual inplementation. Either a dimension must be specified in the type or the argument `a` could be of type `int**` while its dimensions are provided as separate arguments to `dp`. As this is C++, a type of `std::vector< std::vector< int > >` might be more suitable for the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically declare an array on the stack as the size has to be known at compile time. The only way to do this would be by allocating memory for the array on the heap using the `new` keyword, then you could declare the size at run time.

Far easier, however, would be just to use a container class, or in your case, a container of containers like a vector of vector of ints;

```
#include <vector>

vector< vector<int> > arrArray(rows, vector<int>(columns));
```

The syntax might look a bit strange, but breaking it down;

`vector<int>` - a vector of type `int`

`vector< vector<int> >` - a vector of vectors of type `int`

`arrArray(rows, vector<int>(columns));` - here in the first parameter, we are saying; create `rows` number of `vector<int>`'s in our array, and the second parameter initalises the array to some value. If it were just a 2D array of `int`, we might initalise it to `0`, or omit the second parameter and rely on the default value of `int`. But, because our multidimensional vector also contains vectors, we set each row of our main vector to store a vector of `int`'s which holds `columns` amount of integers.

Now you can access the array like you would any other;

```
arrArray[2][0] = 5;
```

You also get all the added benefits that container classes contain, including iterators and a lot of useful class methods for manipulating and checking your array. Once you understand the syntax of creating container classes, you'll find them much easier to work with than arrays. You also don't have to worry about having to manage your own memory, and have the ability to do bounds checking before accessing vector elements.